# Fortran CHARACTER FUNCTION without defined size

Tags: string, function, fortran

I need to write an F90 function that converts a string into uppercase.
Based in [How can I write a to_upper() or to_lower() function in F90?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759375/how-can-i-write-a-to-upper-or-to-lower-function-in-f90) I have already written the following function:

```
CHARACTER*32 FUNCTION TO_UPPER(INP_STR)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  !INPUT
  CHARACTER(*) INP_STR
  !INTERNAL
  INTEGER*4     i,j
  CHARACTER*(LEN(INP_STR)) OUT_STR
  !MAP
  CHARACTER(26), PARAMETER :: CAP = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  CHARACTER(26), PARAMETER :: LOW = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  !Convertion
  OUT_STR = INP_STR
  DO i = 1, LEN(TRIM(INP_STR))
    j = INDEX(LOW,INP_STR(i:i))
    IF (j.GT.0) OUT_STR(i:i) = CAP(j:j)
  END DO
  TO_UPPER = OUT_STR
  RETURN
END FUNCTION TO_UPPER
```

The strings that I will pass to this function have different sizes. Currently I know that the largest input string will have 32 characters, however in the future this may change and I would like to do a function that accepts any string size. Something like:

```
CHARACTER(*) FUNCTION TO_UPPER(INP_STR)
  ...
END FUNCTION TO_UPPER
```

But this will not work because Fortran does not accept CHARACTER(*) functions, so i wanted to do some kind of function that will acept string of any size. Any ideas of how i can solve this?

Comment: Fortran [does accept](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42791082/3157076) so called assumed length character functions results.   But you shouldn't.  However, you may be interested more in [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42787131/3157076).

Comment: Thanks. I think these alternatives will work for me.

Comment: Wait, there is a full example for any length in the answer under the very question you link. This code https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759613/721644 DOES work for any string length. I don't understand your problem.