# Entity with assumed character length at (1) must be a dummy argument or a PARAMETER

Tags: fortran

In the mainline, how to I declare "to_upper" and "string" so as to call this function?

```
Pure Function to_upper (str) Result (string)

!   Changes a string to upper case

    Implicit None

    Character(*), Intent(In) :: str

    Character(LEN(str))      :: string

    Integer :: ic, i
```

```
program tescc
 character (*) to_upper, to_lower
 character (*) tes1,tes2
 tes1='LoWs' tes2=to_upper(tes1)
 print*,tes1,',',tes2
 end
```

```
 gfortran -o tescc tescc.f tescc.f:4:24: 4 |
 character (*) tes1,tes2 |
 1 Error: Entity with assumed character length at (1) must be a dummy argument or a PARAMETER tescc.f:4:29:
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I do not understand your question. Please describe your problem in more detaill. When you use `result`, you do not declare the type of the function name but the type of the result variable.

Comment: So what I wanted to imply: Your coud should work as is, nothing more is needed.

Comment: I'm afraid it's very unclear what you're asking. Please could you explain what you're trying to do in more detail, or make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I refer to:                 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759375/how-can-i-write-a-to-upper-or-to-lower-function-in-f90 my calling routine failes because I do not declare correctlyprogram tescc
        implicit none
        character (*) to_upper, to_lower
        character (*) tes1,tes2,tes3,tes4
        tes1='LoWs'
        tes2=to_upper(tes1)
        tes3='hIgH'
        tes4=to_upper(tes3)
        print*,tes1,',',tes2,',',tes3,',',tes4
        end

        Pure Function to_upper (str) Result (string)

Comment: I refer to:                 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759375/how-can-i-... my calling routine fails because I do not declare correctly:          program tescc
        character (*) to_upper, to_lower
        character (*) tes1,tes2
        tes1='LoWs'
        tes2=to_upper(tes1)
        print*,tes1,',',tes2
        end
         gfortran -o tescc tescc.f
tescc.f:4:24:

    4 |         character (*) tes1,tes2
      |                               1
Error: Entity with assumed character length at (1) must be a dummy argument or a PARAMETER
tescc.f:4:29:

Comment: Do not use comments for code or any other important information. It just became lost here. instead, [edit] your question with the full code and the error message or output. Please do read [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fortran: Initialize character string with unknown length in main program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483961/fortran-initialize-character-string-with-unknown-length-in-main-program)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to declare three strings, one for the function, one which is the input string, and another for the output string. You would first need to end this function. You need to say the function name is a string because that is what it returns.

This function does nothing so you would need to finish writing the function algorithm. But,

Here is an example code to run this function:

```
program main
    implicit none
    character(100) :: to_upper
    character(100) :: some_str, other_str

    some_str = "hello world"

    other_str = to_upper(some_str)

end program main

pure function to_upper (str) Result (string)
   ! Changes a string to upper case
    implicit None

    Character(*), Intent(In) :: str
    Character(LEN(str))      :: string
    Integer :: ic, i
end function
```

Comment: There is no need for the third string. `some_str_str = to_upper(some_str)` is fine.